# select2 - clear all items not working when targeting by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 combobox, from which I want to clear out all items.

If I target the select with an ID, then it works:

```
$("#clearId").click(function(){
  $("#list").empty();
});
```

However, if I target the select with a class, it actually removes the select from the dom:

```
$("#clearClass").click(function(){
    $(".list").empty();
});
```

This can be seen in the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NvrZu/

I need to be able to target the select via a class.

Comment: @PalashMondal Look at the fiddle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dynamically added parent of the select also gets the `.list` class when the plugin wraps the original select, so you're not just removing the options in the select, but the select as well, as you're emptying the parent element.

Excluding the wrapper added by the plugin should solve that problem :

```
$("#clearClass").click(function(){
    $(".list").not('.select2-container').empty();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NvrZu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
                $("#list").empty();
                $("#list").select2('data', null);
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included a (brief) explanation in addition to just code.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/NvrZu/1/

```
$("#clearClass").click(function(){
     $("select.list").empty();
});
```

You do have other element with class `.list` that you don't want to empty

this is div generated by plugin with class **list** -

```
<div class="select2-container list"
```

See On console --> http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/NvrZu/4/